# SSRS Expression to Switch LastName, FirstName to FirstName LastName in field

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

SQL Server 2016
SSRS 2016
IDE Visual Studio 2017

**Problem:** Report Field contains value of `Doe, John`

**Solution/Output:** Using SSRS expression require field to output `John Doe`

Current sample of my expression that gives me an #error when I run preview:

```
=Split(Fields!Name.Value,",")(1).ToString() &","& Split(Fields!Name.Value,",")(0).ToString()
```

I found example above online, however throws an error. Relatively new to SSRS advanced expressions.
I don't have the option to edit the T-SQL query

Comment: *"however throws an error"* and what is that error?

Comment: If the name doesnt have a comma, it is bound to fail. I suppose you have names without , in it.

Comment: @Larnu the error returned in preview is: #Error (in the field where the expression is)

Comment: @shahkalpesh after looking back at the T-SQL query, you are correct.  The SELECT statement for this column/field Name is wrapped in a COALESCE statement as follows: ,COALESCE(d.Name, 'Not Available') AS Name

Comment: You may check for presence of comma in the field and split it only if it has comma. Print the name as it is otherwise.

Comment: @shahkalpesh thanks. Would it make sense to wrap the SSRS expression in an IIF statement to first check for 'Not Available' and if false split the string?

Comment: Yes. Just make sure that it remains "Not Available" and not change it to "#N./A". It will fail again in that case.

Comment: @shahkalpesh unfortunately IIF statement still results in an error Expression used: =IIF(Split(Fields!Name.Value = "Not Available", "Not Available", Split(Fields!Name.Value,",")(1).ToString() &","& Split(Fields!Name.Value,",")(0).ToString())

Comment: Aside: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work...

```
=SWITCH(
    split(Fields!Name.Value, ",").length = 1, Fields!Name.Value,
    True, TRIM(split(Fields!Name.Value + ",", ",")(1))
        + " "
        + TRIM(split(Fields!Name.Value + ",", ",")(0))
    )
```

What I've done here is...
for the first SWITCH expression pair, check if the name has only a single element, if it does return the name (e.g. for "not Applicable". This method is safer as it will handle anything with no commas present.

The second part `True` just acts like an `ELSE`
In this case I've added  a comma to the end of the `Name` field value so that the evaluated string always has at least 1 comma (thus preventing the error). I've also trimmed the results so you don't get unwanted spaces.

We now get these results

[image]